# How can I get the variable importance when creating a random forest with partykit?

Tags: r, random-forest, party

I'm using partykit to create a multi-output random forest. The library party provides a function (impVar) to obtain it directly, but I cannot find an equivalent function in partykit. Is there any way to obtain the variable importance to classify with partykit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. While the tree fitting functions `ctree()` and `mob()` in partykit already supersede the corresponding functionality in the party package, the same is not yet true for `cforest()`. At the moment the latter is a basic re-implementation that has already some new features but also lacks various details, specifically methods for flexible prediction and variable importance. We plan to add these in the future, though.